# Can't invalidate timer swift

Tags: ios, swift, timer

In my app I should use multiple timers but I don't want to add separate timers for every function, how can I create one function that simplifies creating multiple timers, I tried this code below, it works but I can't invalidate timers.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var first: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var second: UILabel!

  var count = 0
  var count2 = 0

  var timer = Timer()
  var timer2 = Timer()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timerWithDifferentIntervals(myTimer: timer, interval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(handle1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    timerWithDifferentIntervals(myTimer: timer2, interval: 1/6, target: self, selector: #selector(handle2), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func handle1() {
    count += 1
    first.text = "\(count)"
}

func handle2() {
    count2 += 1
    second.text = "\(count2)"
}


func timerWithDifferentIntervals(myTimer: Timer, interval: TimeInterval, target: Any, selector: Selector, userInfo: Any?, repeats: Bool) {
    var timers = myTimer
    timers = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: target, selector: selector, userInfo: userInfo, repeats: repeats)
}


@IBAction func stop(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer.invalidate()
    timer2.invalidate()
}

}
```

Comment: by the way sorry for my english)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never actually assign a new value to your variables. The timers you create are not saved anywhere, therefore you cannot invalidate them.

I would recommend the following changes:

```
var timer: Timer? {
   didSet {
      oldValue?.invalidate()
   }
}
var timer2: Timer? {
   didSet {
      oldValue?.invalidate()
   }
}
```

This will make sure the previous timer is always invalidated when assigning a new one. You can then invalidate using `timer = nil` or `timer2 = nil`.

Also, you should return the timer from your method:

```
func timerWithDifferentIntervals(interval: TimeInterval, target: Any, selector: Selector, userInfo: Any?, repeats: Bool) -> Timer {
  return Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: target, selector: selector, userInfo: userInfo, repeats: repeats)
}
```

and use it in following way:

```
timer = timerWithDifferentIntervals(interval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(handle1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Although the method does basically nothing now, so there is no need for it

Answer (score 0):

Add NStimers in an array, and each timer have a tag of its own.

Then whenever you want to invalidate a timer, reach it via the array and invalidate it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you should use below code for timer create and invalidate

```
var timer : NSTimer?

func startTimer(_ timeInterval: Int, _ isRepeat: Bool)
{
  if timer == nil {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval, target: self, selector: "timerFired", userInfo: nil, repeats: isRepeat)
  }
}

func stopTimer()
{
  if timer != nil {
    timer!.invalidate()
    timer = nil
  }
}
```